# Is there any way to access the Touch Accommodations status programmatically in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, uiaccessibility

iOS has an Accessibility settings group for Touch Accommodations.  I'm trying to read whether or not Touch Accommodations is enabled for the iPad from within my running app, programmatically.

For example, in Swift, you can access the "Assistive Touch" status using

```
UIAccessibility.isAssistiveTouchRunning
```

However, I see no similar option for reading the "Touch Accommodations" status.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Check UIAccessibility.isReduceMotionEnabled or go over the views with a for loop and look for UIAccessibilityCustomAction

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but "Reduce Motion" is a different accessibility setting than  "Touch Accommodations", and UIAccessibilityCustomAction is nil on all of my views.